# Как синхронизировать таблицы двух разных БД?

Tags: python, база-данных

Есть две БД.
FireBird и PostgreSQL

Нужно синхронизировать содержимое. Из таблицы PostgreSQL данные прокидывать в FireBird. Как это сделать? В обе таблицы я добавил флаг синхронизации. Типа проведена/не проведена.

Создаю курсор и делаю SELECT из БД1 в поисках необходимых записей. Предположим я их выбрал. А дальше как быть? Как это выборку в другую БД отправить? Создать второй объект курсора, так? А сам запрос как сформировать на основании полученных данных?

```
postcursor.execute('SELECT customer_id, customer_name, customer_data, customer_priority, customer_status, fl_ready FROM CUSTOMER WHERE fl_ready=0')
    postselect_result = postcursor.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А дальше просто цикл по Postgres курсору и insert по одной записи Firebird с условием что такой записи нет

Примерно так.
insert into tab1 values (id, date) 
where (id,date) not in 
(select id,date from tab1 where flag=1)